# Download user's profile image from SharePoint Online website using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, delve

I need to download the profile image of a user from a SharePoint Online website and then insert that image into a PPT. For this, I am using C# code below:

```
string userPhotoURL = "https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=M&username=username@microsoft.com";
using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
        client.Credentials = Utility.GetSharePointOnlineCredentials(); // includes username and SecureString password
        client.DownloadFile(userPhotoURL, "D:\sample.jpg");
    }
// More code to read the D:\sample.jpg and insert it into PPT
```

However, above is returning 403 response.

Note: I need to achieve this from server side.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue myself. Basically I added an extra header while sending the request as below:

```
client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
```